# how to install sudo on msys shell

Tags: linux, command-line, msys

I work with msys shell on windows 8.1 
but when I use "sudo" I get this error

> bash: sudo: command not found

and my $PATH is :

> /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/opt/bin:/c/ProgramData/Oracle/Java/javapath:/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/iCLS Client:/c/Program Files/Intel/iCLS Client:/c/Windows/system32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/c/Program Files/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/DAL:/c/Program Files (x86)/Intel/Intel(R) Management Engine Components/IPT:/d/hex editor/010 Editor:/c/Program Files (x86)/Skype/Phone:/c/Program Files (x86)/NVIDIA Corporation/PhysX/Common:/c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Kits/8.1/Windows Performance Toolkit:/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/110/Tools/Binn:/c/Program Files/Microsoft SQL Server/110/DTS/Binn:/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/110/Tools/Binn:/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/110/Tools/Binn/ManagementStudio:/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0/Common7/IDE/PrivateAssemblies:/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft SQL Server/110/DTS/Binn

how I can install sudo on msys?

Comment: There is probably no real `sudo` for it just like with Cygwin which it is a fork of.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't a U/L question.

Comment: The Answer may simply be "no" -- http://www.mingw.org/search/node/sudo and https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/ look pessimistic.